Hamburger button not expanding in small screen view for Bootstrap 5.3.3
I cannot get the hamburger button to expand on the smallest screen size for my dropdown. I've changed the CDN links and am using bootstrap 5.3.
I've ensured that the ID names are the same and have searched for answers on here and also from googling it.
Can anyone help me? What am I missing?
Here's my coding:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 5 Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384- YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="landing3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Dropdown menu -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light text-black fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="W3_BS5_test1.html" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Logo1.png" alt="logo"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggle">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navbarToggle">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Projects</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="locations.html" class="dropdown-item">Locations</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="blog.html" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="testimonies.html" class="nav-link">Testimonies</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>`

 I've ensured I'm using the CDN links from the Bootstrap 5 website and removed the Popper link which I had in the coding originally (I have seen something which said version 5.3.3 doesn't work with several libraries. I've ensured that the ID names are the same and that it says data-bs-target and data-bs-toggle. Unfortunately none of this seemed to make any difference and the button is still not expanding.

I think id should be navbarToggle NOT #navbarToggle

Yes only data-bs-target should be #navbarToggle and id should be only navbarToggle. https://jsfiddle.net/c79o5Lpy/

thank you so much. This has now worked. I will ensure the id doesn't have a hashtag at the start.
